# Send Mail not working properly on Ubuntu server 10.04

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, sendmail

I am trying to send a test email from ubuntu server 10.04 using the sendmail service.
Below is the command.

```
cat /var/gs/livecron/design.txt | mail -s "Cron Job Duration Notification" sangramsanand@gmail.com
```

Earlier it worked fine, but from past 2 days its not working.  I check the
    **/var/log/mail.log** 
but the file is empty.

I tried reinstalling the sendmail  using  **sudo apt-get install sendmail** and its displaying

```
root@domU-12-31-39-09-29-24:/var/log# sudo apt-get install sendmail
sudo: unable to resolve host domU-12-31-39-09-29-24
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
sendmail is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
python-twisted-core python-pexpect python-twisted-web python-pycurl libx86-1
bc libpciaccess0 python-serial vbetool python-pam python-openssl libffi5
libhal1 hal libhal-storage1 python-dbus pm-utils smartdimmer radeontool
hal-info python-smartpm python-twisted-bin python-gobject
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 63 not upgraded.
```

Please suggest me a solution to fix these issue.